# Ruby on rails: store all specific key values from a hash into an array

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

How can I create an array of all "name_printed" keys in the following hash with nil safe navigation?

```
 {
  "show_data_on_file": "Yes",
  "employees_names_printed_on_badges": [
    {
      "name_printed": "John",
      "badge_id": 12160060
    },
    {
      "name_printed": "Tom",
      "badge_id": 12160080
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Enumerable#pluck`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-pluck). In the case `employees_names_printed_on_badges` returns a falsy value, you invoke `pluck` on an empty array:

```
(data[:employees_names_printed_on_badges] || []).pluck(:name_printed)
# ["John", "Tom"]
```

Or use `&`, which would result in nil if `data[:employees_names_printed_on_badges]&` is nil.

```
data[:employees_names_printed_on_badges]&.pluck(:name_printed)
```

Comment: I was wondering if we could directly dig : name_printed key form this hash without looking at : employees_names_printed_on_badges

Comment: You need to reference first employees_names_printed_on_badges, that would be the point of using a Hash. Or you could map each name_printed from the values that are an array.